# Received incompatible instance in Graphql query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, graphql

When i hit insomnia with this request bellow then it shows this response. How can i solve this issue?

**Request:**

```
query{
    datewiseCoronaCasesList{
        updatedAt,
        affected,
        death,
        recovered
    }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Received incompatible instance \"{'updated_at': datetime.date(2020, 4, 8), 'affected': 137, 'death': 42, 'recovered': 104}\"."
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "datewiseCoronaCasesList": [
            null
        ]
    }
}
```

**My expectation which i have already gotten in errors message but this way:**

```
{
    'updated_at': datetime.date(2020, 4, 8),
    'affected': 137,
    'death': 42,
    'recovered': 104
}
```

**My GraphQL query:**

```
class CoronaQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    datewise_corona_cases_list = graphene.Field(CoronaCaseType)

    def resolve_datewise_corona_cases_list(self, info, **kwargs):
        return CoronaCase.objects.values('updated_at').annotate(
affected=Sum('affected'),death=Sum('death'), recovered=Sum('recovered'))
```

**My model:**

```
class CoronaCase(models.Model):
    affected = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    death = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    recovered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=265, null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Affected from: {}".format(self.district)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under `CoronaQuery` class, since you are returning a list of objects (instances),  `graphene.Field` should be changed to `graphene.List`.

I mean:

```py
class CoronaQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    datewise_corona_cases_list = graphene.List(CoronaCaseType)
```